# Regex check to see if a String contains non digit fails

Tags: java, regex

Why does this fail?

```
String n = "h107";
if (n.matches("\\D+")) {
  System.out.println("non digit in it");
}
```

I had a night sleep over it, and I still not get it.
I got a solution now:

```
if (n.matches(".*\\D+.*")) {
```

But in my (maybe lack of knowledge) the first one should also match. Cause if it has to match a complete String, then what's the point of a '^' character for a line beginning.

Comment: It's hard not to answer by pointing that's just another one retarded java API...

Comment: @dystroy if "retarded" as in "misnamed" then I fully agree ;) Otherwise, when you use it correctly it is pretty good

Comment: @fge It's misnamed and a weak design choice. Using the standard regex conventions here would have enabled us to decide when to match the whole string or not without resorting to the verbose Pattern API for a simple check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the recurring problem of `.matches()`: it is misnamed. It does NOT do regex matching. And the problem is that even other languages have fallen prey to that misnaming (python is one example).

The problem is that it will try to match your *whole* input.

Use a `Pattern`, a `Matcher` and `.find()` instead (`.find()` *does* real regex matching, ie find text that matches anywhere in the input):

```
private static final Pattern NONDIGIT = Pattern.compile("\\D");

// in code
if (NONDIGIT.matcher(n).find())
    // there is a non digit
```

You should in fact use a `Pattern`; `String`'s `.matches()` will recompile a pattern *each time*. With a `Pattern` it is only compiled once.

Comment: Java is a nice language by syntax. But the api's the sun are making are total crap.

Comment: Well, hey, once you get the hang of it, you just forget about how "quirky" it is ;) Anyway, all things considered, Java's regex engine is very good. And the logical separation between a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` makes sense. However, yeah, I do wish that the method names were better. Like a lot of people...

Answer (score 2):

[`String.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) returns true if the *entire* string matches the pattern. Simply change your regular expression to `\d+` which returns true if entire string consists of digits:

```
String n = "h107";
if (!n.matches("\\d+")) {
     System.out.println("non digit in it");
}
```

Comment: That's pretty costly as a solution compared to using a `Pattern`